# Magento 2 Default Catalog Search Page Was Not Working .. it's Blank Page Present

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

I have set new theme and all page are working fine but the catalog search page are blank....

Here i Ad my

> /public_html/app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Project}/Magento_CatalogSearch/layout
>   Default.XMl

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="top.search">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="advanced-search-link" template="Magento_CatalogSearch::advanced/link.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="footer_links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="catalog-search-advanced-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Advanced Search</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">catalogsearch/advanced</argument>
                    <argument name="attributes" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="data-action" xsi:type="string">advanced-search</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Front End Image

> http://prntscr.com/sb9kok

Comment: check console error ...

Comment: run the page and check console network tab error.And find any red color file.click file and check

Comment: You can also show all php errors. Add this in index.php to see magento errors: ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below line in top of your themes "result.phtml" file at path app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Project}/Magento_CatalogSearch/templates/

```
$productList = $block->getProductListHtml();
```

So your file starting should look like below :

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
$productList = $block->getProductListHtml();
?>
<?php if ($block->getResultCount()): ?>
```